# I want to create a section with react where the user can select multiple photos. I used input, file type, but more than one photo cannot be selected

Tags: html, jsx

There is a limit for input file type, you can't choose more than one, how can I increase the number؟

You can only select a photo or a file

```
<input type={"file"} />
```

I did not find anything to solve my probl/em

Comment: What do you mean by "limit"? Why not use multiple input fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the `multiple` attribute in the file chooser.

```html
<input type="file" multiple>
```